# What does "RC" mean in `=SUM(A4:INDIRECT("RC" & G4, 0))`?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have `=SUM(A4:INDIRECT("RC"&G4,0))` in total weight. I understand what it does but I am not able to find what

1. "RC",
2. 0 in `("RC"&G4,0)`stands for

If you have any ideas, please let me know.

[image: Spreadsheet screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the documentation of the [`INDIRECT` function](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

> ## INDIRECT(ref_text, [a1])
>
> The INDIRECT function syntax has the following arguments:
>
> - `Ref_text`: Required. A reference to a cell that contains an A1-style reference, an R1C1-style reference, a name defined as a reference, or a reference to a cell as a text string. If `ref_text` is not a valid cell reference, INDIRECT returns the `#REF!` error value.
>
>   - ...
> - `A1`: Optional. A logical value that specifies what type of reference is contained in the cell `ref_text`.
>
>   - If a1 is TRUE or omitted, `ref_text` is interpreted as an *A1-style reference*.
>   - If a1 is FALSE, `ref_text` is interpreted as an *R1C1-style reference*.

Since your `a1` is 0, the reference is now in **R1C1-style**. In this style `RxCy` refers to row x column y, so R1C2 is equivalent to B1. If you omit the row number then `RCx` is the cell in the same row in the x<sup>th</sup> column

For more information about the RC-style read

- [The beauty of the R1C1 Reference Style](https://tduhameau.wordpress.com/2012/09/27/the-beauty-of-the-r1c1-reference-style/)
- [A1 or R1C1 Notation](https://bettersolutions.com/excel/formulas/cell-references-a1-r1c1-notation.htm)
- [Columns and rows are labeled numerically in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/269866/columns-and-rows-are-labeled-numerically-in-excel)
- [Excel – R1C1 Reference Style vs. A1](https://excelmate.wordpress.com/2013/04/22/excel-r1c1-reference-style-vs-a1/)
- [Reference cells and ranges](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/cells-and-ranges/reference-cells-and-ranges)
- [ADDRESS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/address-function-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89)

In the A1-style RC1 is still valid though. If you scroll to the right then you'll see that after column Z is column AA, AB,... AZ, BA,..., BZ... all the way until the last column (XFD for column 16384). `RC1` means **the cell in the 470<sup>th</sup> column of the first row**

Comment: In short, "RC" returns the same row that the formula is in.

Comment: RC is nothing but a NAMED Data Range,,, ☺

Comment: @RajeshS who said that? did you even try to run the above formula?

Comment: `Ref_text` is reference to a cell either A1-style reference or R1C1-style reference, a NAME defined as a reference,,! A1 style =INDIRECT("Mydata")